# Python import statement only recognizes packages from certain directories?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import

This is one of the weirder issues I've come across and I can't figure out what is causing it.

I have a `from x import x` statement and it only works in certain file directories.

for example, from my `userroot` directory

```
C:\Users\admin>where python
C:\scoop\shims\python.exe

C:\Users\admin>python
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit 
(AM D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
>>> ^Z
```

I can import the package just fine - however when I go to the desktop (which is still apart of my user directory)

```
C:\Users\admin>cd Desktop

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>where python
C:\scoop\shims\python.exe

C:\Users\admin\Desktop>python
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AM D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\scoop\apps\python27\current\lib\site-packages\influxdb\__init__.py",
line 9, in <module>
    from .client import InfluxDBClient
  File "C:\scoop\apps\python27\current\lib\site-packages\influxdb\client.py", li
ne 14, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\scoop\apps\python27\current\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py",
line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\scoop\apps\python27\current\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", l
ine 8, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\scoop\apps\python27\current\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.
py", line 3, in <module>
    import logging
  File "logging.py", line 4, in <module>
    from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
ImportError: cannot import name InfluxDBClient
>>> ^Z
```

So going into my desktop directory, though still using the same python.exe, will not allow my to import the same package.

What makes this more bizarre, if I look at the `sys.path`

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>python
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\python27\\current\\python27.zip', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\pytho
n27\\current\\DLLs', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\python27\\current\\lib', 'C:\\scoop\\apps
\\python27\\current\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\python27\\current\\lib\\l
ib-tk', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\python27\\current', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\python27\\curren
t\\lib\\site-packages']
>>> ^Z
```

And for the root directory -

```
C:\Users\admin\Desktop>cd..

C:\Users\admin>python
Python 2.7.14 (v2.7.14:84471935ed, Sep 16 2017, 20:25:58) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\python27\\current\\python27.zip', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\pytho
n27\\current\\DLLs', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\python27\\current\\lib', 'C:\\scoop\\apps
\\python27\\current\\lib\\plat-win', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\python27\\current\\lib\\l
ib-tk', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\python27\\current', 'C:\\scoop\\apps\\python27\\curren
t\\lib\\site-packages']
>>> ^Z
```

You can see they are exactly the same. I figured it might be an Environmental variable issue, but why would it work in the `userroot` and not on the `useroot/Desktop`? And this doesnt seem to be just a `influxdb` error, `BeautifulSoup` does the same thing.

This is being ran from an elevated cmd prompt on an admin account. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling python. I've tried both python2 and python3. I've tried setting `PYTHONPATH`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Note that your error message was `ImportError: cannot import name InfluxDBClient`, it was *not* `ImportError: No module named influxdb`.  So, it found the module but can't find the name `InfluxDBClient`.  Maybe you have another `influxdb.py` floating around?

Comment: It looks like it fails on `import logging`. Do you perhaps have a `logging.py` on your Desktop?

Comment: I have no other python script on my computer using influxdb.py... I do have logging.py on my desktop - but why would the above line of code `from influxdb import x` start `logging.py` from my desktop?

Comment: Actually, after thinking about this a bit more, the `logging.py` makes sense why it would break. I was calling `influxdb`, `influxdb` was calling `logging` which was in the same folder I was calling `influxdb` from... influxdb was getting confused and trying to use the `logging.py` on my desktop. I feel foolish.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to reply, but I guess I should for others who face the same problem. I was also facing the same problem with

```
from influxdb import InfluxDBClient
```

Then I tried

```
pip install influxdb-client
```

And then

```
from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient
```

It worked for me. Hope this helps.